# twitter4j xAuth authentication

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j, xauth

I'm trying to integrate xauth authentication using the twitter4j library

I've found multiple guides similar to http://www.hiteshagrawal.com/java/twitter-xauth-permission-using-java that all indicate i should have the line:

```
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance(username, password);
```

But this gives me an error, because the getInstance() method doesn't allow the parameter of two strings.

Did the twitter4j library change, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Twitter deprecated Basic authentication and as of Twitter4J 2.2.0, you need to use Twitter#getOAuthAccessToken(id,password) to get the access token.
http://twitter4j.org/en/versions.html#migration21x-22x