# Posting tweets using username and password authentication from Java app

Tags: java, twitter

Up to my knowledge, Twitter has stopped using username and password authentication in order to post tweets from a Java app. However, it allows `OAuth` only (using consumer keys, access tokens etc.).

Is there still any approach or workaround to use username and password based authentication to tweet from a Java app?

Comment: I don't think so. I believe you question is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416133/twitter4j-xauth-authentication

Comment: I improved the title and questions with some rewording for better readability. Please make sure to post what you have tried so far by editing the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there isn't anymore. If you want to be able to use the API you must follow these [steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31015366/what-twitter-access-token-should-i-use-to-automate-tweets/31016011#31016011):

1. Go to Twitter Apps and login with your regular twitter account
   assuming you have one, if not you need to create one.
2. Once signed in click on Create New App button.
3. Fill out the application (Name, description, and whatever else it
   requires).
4. Create your key and access tokens. Share those with users that you
   trust as they'll be used to access the twitter API to read/write
   information.
5. Give the application you created a "Read and Write" permission based
   on what you asked in the question.

Then depending on the software/language you use there's a plenty of existing packages that can help you access and obtain the information from the API.

Comment: hi Leb...can i post to account without app ..using personal account..is there any way to get api key without twitter app

Comment: @Rakeshyadvanshi the way it stands right now, neither of those are possible. You need to have a twitter app in order to obtain an API.